# Supervised Classification with the Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

For a classification of the Cerrado (a region in Brazil) I have chosen to do a supervised classification using the Google Earth Engine. When running the script an error message pop's up in the console stating: "classified: Layer error: Property 'agriculture' of feature '0_0' is missing." This doesn't seems to be the problem for my other classes (city and forest) while I do exactly the same.

city, agriculture and forest are polygons drawn with the polygon tool. landsat is the image I want to classify. Goias is the region I'm focussing on.

What is the meaning of this feature '0_0'?

```js
var forest = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
        [[[[-49.95376110076904, -15.710967112810327],
           [-49.95560646057129, -15.714189425198422],
           [-49.952216148376465, -15.71480909481255],
           [-49.950928688049316, -15.709603811453348],
           [-49.955735206604004, -15.70952118683543]]],
         [[[-50.87038993835449, -14.062653514869359],
           [-50.854811668395996, -14.071645244690382],
           [-50.84751605987549, -14.064984738032894],
           [-50.8626651763916, -14.058906856438178]]],
         [[[-50.811166763305664, -14.182430235294726],
           [-50.838375091552734, -14.184677018750275],
           [-50.833847522735596, -14.201195329073467],
           [-50.80580234527588, -14.200300844289204]]],
         [[[-50.632081031799316, -14.484754464079412],
           [-50.6339693069458, -14.49414484704292],
           [-50.60023784637451, -14.4989645351375]]],
         [[[-50.56989669799805, -14.577186033177513],
           [-50.56955337524414, -14.552928914937938],
           [-50.57933807373047, -14.566220817061826]]],
         [[[-50.89845657348633, -18.015384864469013],
           [-50.89292049407959, -18.01269129442521],
           [-50.898070335388184, -18.01093637057725]]],
         [[[-50.92931270599365, -18.013793214420286],
           [-50.925493240356445, -18.018690553238297],
           [-50.92193126678467, -18.013017789956983],
           [-50.92467784881592, -18.011058807691924]]],
         [[[-50.90643882751465, -18.011058807691924],
           [-50.90373516082764, -18.01036499625073],
           [-50.90437889099121, -18.006283697189883],
           [-50.90643882751465, -18.006283697189883]]],
         [[[-50.87399482727051, -17.982896032077118],
           [-50.878329277038574, -17.97950803295561],
           [-50.88137626647949, -17.985794148396778],
           [-50.884766578674316, -17.984651234967618],
           [-50.8857536315918, -17.985794148396778],
           [-50.882019996643066, -17.990651447894532]]],
         [[[-50.917725563049316, -17.979059016144365],
           [-50.914249420166016, -17.981671461584988],
           [-50.90897083282471, -17.97697719600834],
           [-50.90939998626709, -17.974936172047833],
           [-50.91085910797119, -17.976650633759945]]],
         [[[-50.90394973754883, -17.97358908331176],
           [-50.899529457092285, -17.97501781345918],
           [-50.89794158935547, -17.971466377179688],
           [-50.902276039123535, -17.96795569182738],
           [-50.90682506561279, -17.96909871332269]]]]),
    goias = /* color: #ffc82d */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-53.89773987402128, -17.737335150077946],
          [-53.21656208374657, -18.780701454086767],
          [-50.93127514381945, -19.71426205863078],
          [-46.953989190809466, -18.46836077330379],
          [-45.76744438500839, -14.848185932899527],
          [-45.899312773543386, -12.69278776942265],
          [-48.86573729240354, -12.585603620983632],
          [-50.2225991477078, -12.338855625969925],
          [-51.73879790880113, -15.224867030408598],
          [-52.07001767927636, -15.322314089978098],
          [-52.44591109792566, -15.65224412638864]]]),
    city = /* color: #00ffff */ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
        [[[[-47.92356491088867, -15.824128602644778],
           [-47.92081832885742, -15.837010357573558],
           [-47.90245056152344, -15.826275618823361],
           [-47.8809928894043, -15.80563028827748],
           [-47.89266586303711, -15.798692984390442]]],
         [[[-48.13058853149414, -15.823798290439452],
           [-48.11857223510742, -15.823302821119514],
           [-48.108787536621094, -15.831725634384997],
           [-48.12681198120117, -15.841799518532302],
           [-48.11634063720703, -15.851047232007138],
           [-48.100032806396484, -15.836349774735691],
           [-48.07668685913086, -15.830899883899415],
           [-48.09385299682617, -15.800840270519277],
           [-48.11634063720703, -15.799188513979754],
           [-48.12440872192383, -15.786469537412923],
           [-48.140201568603516, -15.790103612200987]]],
         [[[-48.07342529296875, -15.804474087471961],
           [-48.05419921875, -15.826771080856748],
           [-48.060035705566406, -15.798032276385078],
           [-48.073768615722656, -15.803317880062274]]],
         [[[-48.1230354309082, -15.884896851962742],
           [-48.119773864746094, -15.898930392135671],
           [-48.06364059448242, -15.87944827271288],
           [-48.07394027709961, -15.855505799598921]]],
         [[[-48.06621551513672, -15.912632786660408],
           [-48.04939270019531, -15.922702625654379],
           [-48.05574417114258, -15.908340570752602],
           [-48.04269790649414, -15.902892626277593],
           [-48.04664611816406, -15.899425675672019],
           [-48.07119369506836, -15.902232259341346]]],
         [[[-47.78572082519531, -15.89992095798885],
           [-47.77627944946289, -15.907515134108964],
           [-47.769412994384766, -15.903718081898417],
           [-47.77799606323242, -15.891666093512773]]],
         [[[-47.88991928100586, -15.846423428228759],
           [-47.87395477294922, -15.85055182952652],
           [-47.867088317871094, -15.841634376941688],
           [-47.8754997253418, -15.831065034266503]]],
         [[[-48.035831451416016, -15.806786482478387],
           [-48.015403747558594, -15.814714493330174],
           [-48.00870895385742, -15.790433979404416],
           [-48.04664611816406, -15.793902802515186]]],
         [[[-47.849063873291016, -15.745168658461244],
           [-47.837562561035156, -15.758881482187945],
           [-47.8318977355957, -15.768298186245215],
           [-47.83498764038086, -15.749629558126074],
           [-47.87137985229492, -15.724184595030325]]],
         [[[-49.28895950317383, -16.659872383959307],
           [-49.29119110107422, -16.668259437653628],
           [-49.280033111572266, -16.683552530348035],
           [-49.27196502685547, -16.66020129494842],
           [-49.28861618041992, -16.658721191047853]]],
         [[[-49.28947448730469, -16.722519717319],
           [-49.279518127441406, -16.71840962984931],
           [-49.26338195800781, -16.727451705356305],
           [-49.2597770690918, -16.715121496109433],
           [-49.27042007446289, -16.713970635912027],
           [-49.289817810058594, -16.693911672384527]]],
         [[[-49.34560775756836, -16.770847694791637],
           [-49.33479309082031, -16.77528536317065],
           [-49.3260383605957, -16.770354614132874],
           [-49.34080123901367, -16.763944449213486]]],
         [[[-49.33582305908203, -16.655596489686744],
           [-49.33067321777344, -16.666450496373013],
           [-49.321231842041016, -16.6666149462869],
           [-49.32294845581055, -16.65115603689586],
           [-49.3121337890625, -16.641123523891356],
           [-49.323463439941406, -16.64013669096455],
           [-49.34440612792969, -16.652307275281608]]]]),
    image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC8_SR"),
    agriculture = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
        [[[[-45.955810546875, -14.076641147746095],
           [-45.924224853515625, -14.061988097202269],
           [-45.797882080078125, -13.963388675891327],
           [-45.8734130859375, -13.928069145372694],
           [-45.99220275878906, -13.998036539606128]]],
         [[[-45.874786376953125, -14.12325823495085],
           [-45.874786376953125, -14.152555522222587],
           [-45.87409973144531, -14.18917181904185],
           [-45.8349609375, -14.19383165093469],
           [-45.78620910644531, -14.148560659841655],
           [-45.847320556640625, -14.06065595513735],
           [-45.913238525390625, -14.099284922844143]]],
         [[[-46.13433837890625, -14.138573196735809],
           [-46.13433837890625, -14.09662106589108],
           [-46.175537109375, -14.05266293986954],
           [-46.198883056640625, -14.056659482401876],
           [-46.21124267578125, -14.1325805083437]]],
         [[[-46.201629638671875, -13.81274334991904],
           [-46.193389892578125, -13.91607260401736],
           [-46.12335205078125, -13.872079964542497],
           [-45.962677001953125, -13.82941246714161],
           [-45.935211181640625, -13.749389841111972],
           [-46.1810302734375, -13.736050073136349]]],
         [[[-46.21467590332031, -13.558559225740643],
           [-46.14738464355469, -13.571241563074146],
           [-46.138458251953125, -13.559226734063092],
           [-46.19407653808594, -13.532524939185093]]],
         [[[-45.578155517578125, -14.576938127714245],
           [-45.46073913574219, -14.455293324015502],
           [-45.49919128417969, -14.449973994986367],
           [-45.65574645996094, -14.572286279238748],
           [-45.69419860839844, -14.629430744817604],
           [-45.61180114746094, -14.584912496585007]]],
         [[[-45.59497833251953, -15.266631865983076],
           [-45.533180236816406, -15.270275113711289],
           [-45.51807403564453, -15.289152747755958],
           [-45.518760681152344, -15.275905463068401],
           [-45.517730712890625, -15.23085844143626],
           [-45.487518310546875, -15.227877047992555],
           [-45.52082061767578, -15.197729476629094],
           [-45.56304931640625, -15.205018295784908],
           [-45.552406311035156, -15.252720702239158]]],
         [[[-45.591888427734375, -15.199386048559994],
           [-45.560646057128906, -15.198060792056202],
           [-45.554466247558594, -15.175530157957471],
           [-45.607337951660156, -15.167577595475684]]],
         [[[-45.751190185546875, -15.428529514464561],
           [-45.748443603515625, -15.405361690934004],
           [-45.718231201171875, -15.400065825806683],
           [-45.753936767578125, -15.366301517721318],
           [-45.775909423828125, -15.413305235719099]]],
         [[[-48.28216552734375, -16.494855107721587],
           [-48.25864791870117, -16.497324042366905],
           [-48.26774597167969, -16.520695062112992],
           [-48.23530197143555, -16.51460570242487],
           [-48.23616027832031, -16.485143659165615],
           [-48.278045654296875, -16.479217790217742]]]]);
           
var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'];

var cloudy_water_landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_SR')
    .filterBounds(goias)
    .filterDate('2016-06-01', '2016-07-10')
    .median()
    .set('SENSOR_ID', 'OLI_TIRS');

var datamask =  cloudy_water_landsat.select('cfmask_conf');
var mask = datamask.eq(1);
var water_landsat = cloudy_water_landsat.updateMask(mask);

var datawater =  water_landsat.select('cfmask');
var not_water = datawater.eq(1);
var water = not_water.not();
var landsat = water_landsat.updateMask(water);

var RGB = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: -2000,
  max: 2000,
  gamma: [1,1,1],
  };

Map.addLayer(landsat, RGB, 'RGB');

var agriculture = ee.Feature (landsat.clip(agriculture));
var city = ee.Feature (landsat.clip(city));
var forest = ee.Feature (landsat.clip(forest));

var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection([agriculture,city,forest]);
  
var training = landsat.sampleRegions(
  {
  collection: polygons,
  properties: ['agriculture','city', 'forest'],
  scale: 500
  });

var classifier = ee.Classifier.svm(
  {
  kernelType: 'RBF',
  gamma: 0.1,
  cost: 10
  });

var trained = classifier.train(training, ('agriculture','city', 'forest'), bands);

var classified = landsat.classify(trained);

Map.addLayer(classified,{},'classified');
Map.setCenter(-49.515, -15.824);
```

Comment: it'd be better if you post a link to the code editor, so we can have the entire code including the polygons, run it and evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument that you pass to `classifier.train()` is the name of the band with class property. This should be an integer. You're never adding a class band to the landsat pixels, so it fails on the first feature of the feature collection (the feature with the id `0_0`). JavaScript doesn't have tuples like Python (or whichever language you're more used to), so the code `('agriculture','city', 'forest')` resolves to the last element in the parens (in this case, `forest`). So you're telling GEE that your class band is `forest`, and when it doesn't find a `forest` band it throws an error. It will be clear that you're not adding a class band if you print the first element of the feature collection using `print(training.first());`

What you should be doing instead is adding a band to the pixels under your different polygons, something like `landType`, which will have a value of 0, 1 or 2 depending on whether it is agriculture, city or forest.

Comment: This was really useful. Thanks a lot!